# TCP IP Socket is destroying during Server and Client Communication ( net: NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcpclient, tcpserver

I am new in TCP IP client server communication.

```
import net from "net";
private static server: net.Server;
private static socket: net.Socket | null = null;

private static createTCPServer(): Promise<{ error: boolean; message?: string; result?: any }> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const port = 8192;
      this.server = net.createServer((socket) => {
        // Connection Keep alive forever
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        console.log(false, "TCP IP client connected." , { ClientIp: socket.remoteAddress , Port: socket.remotePort });
        
        this.socket = socket;
        this.promiseResolve = resolve;
        this.promiseReject = reject;

        this.handleIncomingData(this.promiseResolve, false);

        socket.on('error', (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(true, "TCP IP Client connection reset, Try again later...", err);
          } else {
            console.log(true, "TCP IP Client Socket error: Try again later...", err);
          }
          reject({error: true, message: "TCP Client connection problem, Try again later...", result : err });
        });

        // Handle Client Disconnection
        socket.on('end', () => {
          console.log(false, "TCP IP Client Disconnected ..", { ClientIp: socket.remoteAddress , Port: socket.remotePort });
          reject({ error: true, message: "TCP IP Client Disconnected." });
          }
        );

        socket.on('close', hadError => {
          if (hadError) {
            console.log(true, "TCP IP Client Disconnected with error.", hadError);
          } else {
            console.log(false, "TCP IP Client Disconnected gracefully.", hadError);
          }
          reject({ error: true, message: "TCP IP Client Disconnected.", result: hadError});``
        });
      });

      this.server.listen(8192, () => {
        console.log(false, `TCP Server Listen at port 8192`);
        resolve({ error: false, message: `TCP Server Listen at port ${port}` }); // Resolve the promise when the server is successfully listening
      });

      this.server.on("error", (err) => {
        console.log(true, `TCP Server error: ${err}`);
        reject({ error: true, message: "TCP Server Error.", result: err }); // Reject the promise if there's an error starting the server
      });
    });
  }
```

This is my TCP IP Server code which is listen on 8192 port when my nodejs application starts. I have only single client server communication only.
After this the TCP client connects and communication starts. But after some attempts when i send TCP packet from my server to client. socket is destroying.
How i identify this ?

```
if (!socket.destroyed) {
      socket.write(packet);
   } else {
      reject({ error: true, message: "Socket Destroyed Try again later." });
   }
```

```
let onResponseReceived;
onResponseReceived = (response) => {
        if (response) {
          console.log(false, `Received data from NMDL Client, Data ${this.socket.listenerCount("data")}.`, response.toString().trim());
          resultResponse = Client_Response(response.toString().trim(), resolve);
            this.socket.removeListener("data", onResponseReceived);
}
}
```

And this is how i am handling the TCP IP response which i am received from NMDL client.

I don't want to destroy the socket. I want to reuse the same socket.

To temporary resolve this issue, I restart my nodejs server or a client to solve this issue.

Application flow is : -

**Step 1** - Nodejs server starts <------------------- TCP client connects

**Ways to receive response from client : -**

**Step 2**

1. I am receiving continuously response packets from client.
2. When i send some packet then i am receiving response. (During this i am facing socket destroying issue).

Any idea about this issue ?
I am not able to identify why this issue comes.

I don't want to destroy the socket. I want to reuse the same socket.